# Data is not connected to tableView

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, tableview

I'm building an app, which has three tableViews: One for clubs, which leads to another for members and this leads to transactions. The first two tableViews plus their "add" controller are working, whilst the third one isn't. The add controller works as far as I know, because I know that the transaction gets saved to Core Data. But the transaction isn't displayed in the tableView and I have no idea how I can fix this because this is my first App.

The Transaction Vc Code

```swift
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import CoreData

class TransactionViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTransaction: UITableView!

    let dateFromatter = DateFormatter()

    var member: Member?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dateFromatter.timeStyle = .long
        dateFromatter.dateStyle = .long

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableViewTransaction.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addNewTransaction(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "newTransaction", sender: self)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? AddTransactionViewController else {
            return
        }
        destination.member = member
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return member?.transactions?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableViewTransaction.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transactionCell", for: indexPath)
        if let transaction = member?.transactions?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = transaction.reason

            if let date = transaction.date {
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFromatter.string(from: date)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }















   @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {
        let mailComposeVC = configureMailController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.present(mailComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            showMailError()
        }
    }
    func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mailComposerVC.setSubject("MAHNUNG")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Hey, ich habe gesehen, dass dein Kontostand in der Buchhaltung zu tief ist. Ich bitte dich daher schnellst möglich mir das Geld zu bringen. Gruss", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
}

    func showMailError() {
        let senMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could not send email", message: "Dein Gerät konnte die Email nicht senden.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        senMailErrorAlert.addAction(dismiss)
        self.present(senMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The addTransaction Code:

```swift
import UIKit

class AddTransactionViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var reasonTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var member: Member?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        reasonTextField.delegate = self
        amountTextField.delegate = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        reasonTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        amountTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

    @IBAction func saveTransaction(_ sender: Any) {
        let reason = reasonTextField.text
        let date = datePicker.date
        let moneyText = amountTextField.text ?? ""
        let money = Double(moneyText) ?? 0.0

        if let transaction = Trancsaction(money: money, reason: reason, date: date) {
            member?.addToRawTransactions(transaction)

            do {
                try transaction.managedObjectContext?.save()

                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            } catch {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Transaktion konnte nicht gespeichert werden", message: "Bitte wiederholen Sie ihre Eingabe", preferredStyle: .alert)
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
}

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
}
```

Core Data:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Trancsaction)
public class Trancsaction: NSManagedObject {
    var date: Date? {
        get {
            return rawDate as Date?
      }
        set {
            rawDate = newValue as NSDate?

        }
    }

    convenience init?(money: Double, reason: String?, date: Date?) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(entity: Trancsaction.entity() , insertInto: context)

        self.date = date
        self.money = money
        self.reason = reason
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new Transaction Controller pops off, but Transaction isn't shown in the tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022762/add-a-new-transaction-controller-pops-off-but-transaction-isnt-shown-in-the-ta)

Comment: @Koes that was my question, but it seems that nobody understood my question

Comment: There is no code, we can't guess what's wrong in it. Define "yes it's really saved in CoreData".

Comment: Then edit your first question, asking it again is not encouraged. If this is your first app, I *highly* recommend that you read Apple's documentation on ViewControllers and how to pass data between them. Core Data is not an easy subject either.

Comment: @Larme I mean to know it, because I have a do catch block in the add controller. In the do part is the save function and the pop of function. the pop of function works, so I think that the save function has to work as well.

Comment: @Koen I'm going to do this. I did almost everything from a tutorial which is almost the same. The only difference is, that there are just two tableViews so I think that has to be same or am I wrong??

Comment: @TheClubApp Please share your code. Otherwise it'll stay a guessing game.

Comment: @Koen I added both. The mail should not be a problem I think.

Comment: I think you need to do some basic debugging here. Put break points at critical parts, eg at `prepare(for segue:)` and `cellForRowAt`. Then inspect the variables, are they real, do they make sense? And where do you save to Core Data?

Comment: @Koen I'm saving to core data with the subclasses which can be created and added the things like the guy in the tutorial. And what do you mean at critical points?

Comment: @Koen I added the core data class to the answer as well

Comment: With critical parts, I just mean lines in your code where you could find more info about what could go wrong. So if you set a breakpoint, you can maybe get more info. Good luck!

Comment: @Koen so I can just watch where my problem is?

Comment: Exactly! Programming is much more than copying code from a guy in a tutorial and then hoping it works.

Comment: @Koen Ok nice :D Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @TheClubApp You're welcome. Please report back when you have found a solution!